# Displays on Thunderbolt dock stopped working

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, dock, displayport, thunderbolt

During a recent kernel update, my Thunderbolt dock (a Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Gen 2) stopped working. My computer (A Lenovo Thinkpad P50) still responds to the mouse and keyboard connected to the dock, but my two displays (connected over Displayport) don't get any signal.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, at kernel version 5.15.0-52-generic which isn't working, just as the previous version (5.15.0-50-generic) also isn't working. Booting into 5.15.0-48-generic makes the displays work again. I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 on the other disk, which never stopped working. From Windows, I also made sure that the firmware of the dock is updated to the latest version.

I tried unplugging and re-plugging the USB-C cable, which doesn't do anything, just as restarting with the cable plugged in doesn't work either. So far, the only way I've found to make it work is to boot into a previous version of the kernel. Is there anything else I can do to make it work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm, figured it out.

...

Just kidding, here's the solution that worked for me. I noticed that Ubuntu kept telling me, that it had kept certain packages back when I tried to run a `sudo apt upgrade`. Most of them was related to lib-nvidia. So I tried changing the driver from proprietary nvidia to x.org nouveau drivers, which didn't work. After a restart, the Drivers settings page showed the driver as being manually installed, but at least I could now install the packages Ubuntu had kept back. After a restart, it still didn't work. What ultimately solved the issue was the following command:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers install` (followed by a restart)